# StreamSets processor cant find the Redis libs

Tags: java, docker, redis, docker-compose, streamsets

I have a two containers with Redis and StreamSets. I want to write custom processor in Java and put to pipeline. But when I add code from tutorial to processor, send jar to lib and try to start I got an exceptions. Could you help me please?

Processor tutorials - https://github.com/streamsets/tutorials/blob/master/tutorial-processor/readme.md

Redis tutorial - https://dzone.com/articles/quickstart-how-to-use-redis-on-java

```
  redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    command: redis-server


  streamsets:
    build:
      context: "."
      args:
        SDC_LIBS: streamsets-datacollector-apache-kafka_2_0-lib                ports:
      - 18630:18630
    volumes:
      - ./user-libs:/opt/streamsets-datacollector-3.9.0/user-libs
```

Initiation in sampleprocessor:

```
  @Override
  protected List<ConfigIssue> init() {
      ....
      Config config = new Config();
      config.useSingleServer().setAddress("redis://redis:6379");
      redisson = Redisson.create(config);
      ... }



  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.redisson</groupId>
      <artifactId>redisson</artifactId>
      <version>3.10.4</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
```

The tests of code of processor successfully works.

Logs

```
streamsets_1  | 2020-03-21 14:00:19,954 [user:] [pipeline:] [runner:] [thread:main] [stage:] ERROR Main - Abnormal exit: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/redisson/api/RedissonClient;

streamsets_1  | java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/redisson/api/RedissonClient;
streamsets_1  |         at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
streamsets_1  |         at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
streamsets_1  |         at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicFields(Class.java:2614)
streamsets_1  |         at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicFields(Class.java:2629)
streamsets_1  |         at java.lang.Class.getFields(Class.java:1557)
streamsets_1  |         at com.streamsets.datacollector.definition.ConfigDefinitionExtractor.validate(ConfigDefinitionExtractor.java:82)
streamsets_1  |         at com.streamsets.datacollector.definition.ConfigDefinitionExtractor.validate(ConfigDefinitionExtractor.java:65)
streamsets_1  |         at com.streamsets.datacollector.definition.StageDefinitionExtractor.validate(StageDefinitionExtractor.java:141)
streamsets_1  |         at com.streamsets.datacollector.definition.StageDefinitionExtractor.extract(StageDefinitionExtractor.java:197)
streamsets_1  |         at com.streamsets.datacollector.stagelibrary.ClassLoaderStageLibraryTask.loadStages(ClassLoaderStageLibraryTask.java:557)
streamsets_1  |         at com.streamsets.datacollector.stagelibrary.ClassLoaderStageLibraryTask.initTask(ClassLoaderStageLibraryTask.java:278)
streamsets_1  |         at com.streamsets.datacollector.task.AbstractTask.init(AbstractTask.java:62)
streamsets_1  |         at com.streamsets.datacollector.task.CompositeTask.initTask(CompositeTask.java:44)
streamsets_1  |         at com.streamsets.datacollector.task.AbstractTask.init(AbstractTask.java:62)
streamsets_1  |         at com.streamsets.datacollector.task.TaskWrapper.init(TaskWrapper.java:40)
streamsets_1  |         at com.streamsets.datacollector.main.Main.lambda$doMain$1(Main.java:123)
streamsets_1  |         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
streamsets_1  |         at com.streamsets.datacollector.security.SecurityUtil.doAs(SecurityUtil.java:92)
streamsets_1  |         at com.streamsets.datacollector.main.Main.doMain(Main.java:158)
streamsets_1  |         at com.streamsets.datacollector.main.DataCollectorMain.main(DataCollectorMain.java:53)
streamsets_1  |         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
streamsets_1  |         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
streamsets_1  |         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
streamsets_1  |         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
streamsets_1  |         at com.streamsets.pipeline.BootstrapMain.bootstrap(BootstrapMain.java:351)
streamsets_1  |         at com.streamsets.pipeline.BootstrapMain.main(BootstrapMain.java:110)
streamsets_1  | Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.redisson.api.RedissonClient
streamsets_1  |         at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
streamsets_1  |         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
streamsets_1  |         at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
streamsets_1  |         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
streamsets_1  |         at com.streamsets.pipeline.SDCClassLoader.loadClass(SDCClassLoader.java:353)
streamsets_1  |         at com.streamsets.pipeline.SDCClassLoader.loadClass(SDCClassLoader.java:316)
streamsets_1  |         at com.streamsets.pipeline.SDCClassLoader.loadClass(SDCClassLoader.java:353)
streamsets_1  |         at com.streamsets.pipeline.SDCClassLoader.loadClass(SDCClassLoader.java:316)
streamsets_1  |         ... 26 more
streamsets_1  |
streamsets_1  | Abnormal exit: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/redisson/api/RedissonClient;Check STDERR for more details
streamsets_1  |
streamsets_1  | java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/redisson/api/RedissonClient;
streamsets_1  |         at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
streamsets_1  |         at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
streamsets_1  |         at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicFields(Class.java:2614)
streamsets_1  |         at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicFields(Class.java:2629)
streamsets_1  |         at java.lang.Class.getFields(Class.java:1557)
streamsets_1  |         at com.streamsets.datacollector.definition.ConfigDefinitionExtractor.validate(ConfigDefinitionExtractor.java:82)
streamsets_1  |         at com.streamsets.datacollector.definition.ConfigDefinitionExtractor.validate(ConfigDefinitionExtractor.java:65)
streamsets_1  |         at com.streamsets.datacollector.definition.StageDefinitionExtractor.validate(StageDefinitionExtractor.java:141)
streamsets_1  |         at com.streamsets.datacollector.definition.StageDefinitionExtractor.extract(StageDefinitionExtractor.java:197)
streamsets_1  |         at com.streamsets.datacollector.stagelibrary.ClassLoaderStageLibraryTask.loadStages(ClassLoaderStageLibraryTask.java:557)
streamsets_1  |         at com.streamsets.datacollector.stagelibrary.ClassLoaderStageLibraryTask.initTask(ClassLoaderStageLibraryTask.java:278)
streamsets_1  |         at com.streamsets.datacollector.task.AbstractTask.init(AbstractTask.java:62)
streamsets_1  |         at com.streamsets.datacollector.task.CompositeTask.initTask(CompositeTask.java:44)
streamsets_1  |         at com.streamsets.datacollector.task.AbstractTask.init(AbstractTask.java:62)
streamsets_1  |         at com.streamsets.datacollector.task.TaskWrapper.init(TaskWrapper.java:40)
streamsets_1  |         at com.streamsets.datacollector.main.Main.lambda$doMain$1(Main.java:123)
streamsets_1  |         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
streamsets_1  |         at com.streamsets.datacollector.security.SecurityUtil.doAs(SecurityUtil.java:92)
streamsets_1  |         at com.streamsets.datacollector.main.Main.doMain(Main.java:158)
streamsets_1  |         at com.streamsets.datacollector.main.DataCollectorMain.main(DataCollectorMain.java:53)
streamsets_1  |         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
streamsets_1  |         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
streamsets_1  |         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
streamsets_1  |         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
streamsets_1  |         at com.streamsets.pipeline.BootstrapMain.bootstrap(BootstrapMain.java:351)
streamsets_1  |         at com.streamsets.pipeline.BootstrapMain.main(BootstrapMain.java:110)
streamsets_1  | Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.redisson.api.RedissonClient
streamsets_1  |         at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
streamsets_1  |         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
streamsets_1  |         at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
streamsets_1  |         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
streamsets_1  |         at com.streamsets.pipeline.SDCClassLoader.loadClass(SDCClassLoader.java:353)
streamsets_1  |         at com.streamsets.pipeline.SDCClassLoader.loadClass(SDCClassLoader.java:316)
streamsets_1  |         at com.streamsets.pipeline.SDCClassLoader.loadClass(SDCClassLoader.java:353)
streamsets_1  |         at com.streamsets.pipeline.SDCClassLoader.loadClass(SDCClassLoader.java:316)
streamsets_1  |         ... 26 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is likely your [dependency scope](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope). You have specified `provided`, which is defined as:

> This is much like `compile`, but indicates you expect the JDK or a container to provide the dependency at runtime. For example, when building a web application for the Java Enterprise Edition, you would set the dependency on the Servlet API and related Java EE APIs to scope `provided` because the web container provides those classes. This scope is only available on the compilation and test classpath, and is not transitive.

You should specify `compile` scope.